# Non-greedy pattern with advance characters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-greedy

I have a simple pattern that I want to match. In this sentence:

```
great. This is great&great&great. great.
```

I want to match *only* the 'great' words immediately *following* 'This is'. So the first great would *not* be returned, but the next three have to be. The last should not be.

My expression is

```
This is (great&)*?(great)
```

But this returns only the first great. I read up about greedy and non-greedy patterns, and it works great when I don't have to worry about the advance 'This is'. But these advance characters check is important for my use case. How would I get the required result?

I am able to make this work with:

```
This is (great&){0}(great)
```

for the first match,

```
This is (great&){1}(great)
```

for the second, and so on. But it is a cumbersome solution, and I think I am missing something about the behavior of non-greedy patterns. Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Edited the question to more accurately reflect my problem. Earlier the condition about the last 'great' was not present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and match what you don't want and use a capturing group for `great` between word boundaries.

```
^.*?This is |\b(great)\b
```

- `^` Start of string
- `.*?This is`  Match the first occurrence of `This is`  using a lazy quantifier `.*?`
- `|` Or
- `\b(great)\b` Capture great between word boundaries in group 1

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3mUNdJ/1)

**Update**

A possible solution to the updated question might be using 2 positive lookbehinds inside an alternation.

```
(?:(?<=\bThis is )|(?<=\S))\bgreat\b
```

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?<=\bThis is )` positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is `This is`
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<=\S)` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is a non whitespace char
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `\bgreat\b` Match great between word boundaries

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BBj9kH/1)

Comment: Thanks. That's an interesting answer. That raises an additional problem for me. If there is a 'great' in the next sentence, I don't want this to be captured. I will modify the question to reflect this. How would I solve that?

Comment: @Pradical2190 That is actually changing the question. My current answer reflects the original question. What is the rule to match the 3 times great but not the last one?

Comment: Agreed, and upvoted! But sorry your method raised a problem I did not anticipate earlier.

Comment: @Pradical2190 Perhaps like this https://regex101.com/r/ynGy43/1

Comment: Perfect! Can you update the answer? I will accept it. An explanation, if possible, would be nice.

Comment: @Pradical2190 I realized that while that pattern works for the example, it also matches `&great` only https://regex101.com/r/LLpOk2/1. For that not to work you could make use of infinite lookbehind which is supported using the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) The pattern could then be `(?<=\bThis is \S*)\bgreat\b`. You can see it working on regex101 by selecting ECMA script (which is a different engine) See https://regex101.com/r/QF1nAp/1 You can see it working in Python here https://rextester.com/YGFP31452